# registering a simple gimp python script

Tags: gimp

I'm a bit puzzled because I'm not able to register **any** python script in Gimp (2.8).
I've tried to follow [the docs](https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/) there are two complete examples, clothify and echo, I've tried to put both on my ~/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/ but they doesn't seems to get registered. 
At the end of the page there is the test using console invocation and I got:

```
batch command experienced an execution error:
Error: ( : 1) eval: unbound variable: python-fu-console-echo
```

I've tried with other plugins, and restarting with a new ~/.gimp-2.8 dir

What do you suggest? (I'm on Ubuntu 15.10)

Comment: Got downvoted? I see many questions on gimp here got downvoted maybe because there is nobody able to reply? Someone just hate it?

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted such a question without a comment. Perhaps because your question is more related to the installation of the application and more suitable for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: Downvotes happen if something isn't about graphic design - basic usage of the applications is offtopic here. There's SuperUser for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered the reason why the plug-ins didn't get registered: apparently the file need to have the *execution* bit

> chmod +x plugin.py

Hope it helps someone who stumble upon this problem in the future

Comment: Hi diramaziono, don't forget to mark your answer as accepted if it solved your problem. This prevents it from showing up in the feed and list of unanswered questions! Thanks

Comment: it says I can accept my own answer in two days. Maybe there are other way to mark as solved?

Comment: No problem. I don't think there is any way around that. Just wait two days :)